# <col class="slick"> does not apply class to the columns of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, col

My understanding of col is that it may be used to indicate a class for all the elements in a table's column.  This doesn't seem to be working for me though.  I can apply the class to individual td's, but I want col to help me avoid this.

Here is the html head:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 .slick {
  background-color:#b0c4de; /*This always works*/
  border-style:solid; /*This doesn't work when only applied to a <col>*/
  border-width:5px;
 }
</style>
</head>
```

Interestingly, the background color always works, but the border sometime fails.

Here is the html body:

```
<body>
<table><tbody>
 <colgroup>
  <col class="slick" />
  <col class="slick" />
 </colgroup>
 <tr id="r1">
  <td><label >Planner/Scheduler/Estimators</label></td>
  <td class="slick"><label >2010</label></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
```

Removing the tbody or colgroup tags does not seem to matter.  The background is present in both elements; the border is only applied to the second element, where the class is specified in the td tag.

I had a hunch that border wouldn't work with col, but Firebug shows that the slick style isn't applied to the left column at all.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to w3 schools, only the width attribute works in Firefox. It also doesn't look like the border attribute is supported at all.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

Comment: Further, his link to w3schools says this: "Add the style attribute to the <col> tag, and let CSS take care of backgrounds, width and borders. These are the ONLY CSS properties that work with the <col> tag."

Comment: Alright, I was thinking that col was sort of a stronger application.  That is, I thought setting a class would basically force all the td's to have that class, and that the CSS would completely apply.

Comment: I did check out that page, but I didn't quite understand what it meant when it was saying that certain attributes didn't work.  I was thinking of class as an entirely separate attribute which would allow CSS to work in all ways.

Looks like this won't work, thanks guys! :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [CSS 2.1 specification defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns) that the different border properties only apply when you set `border-collapse: collapse;` on the related `<table>` element.

Furthermore, according to CSS 2.1 there are only very few properties, that can be used to style columns (with restrictions):

- border properties (require `border-collapse: collapse;` on the related `<table>`element)
- background properties (only apply if the cell and row background is transparent)
- `width`
- `visibility` (value `collapse` avoids rendering of the cells, cells spanning into other columns are clipped)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to apply classes to every td.

You can simply style the td's:

```
 td {
  background-color:#b0c4de;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
 }
```