# Why can't I hide a table column in CSS using the <col> property?

Tags: css

I found how I can hide a table column in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682536/how-can-i-hide-certain-table-column-in-a-html-table-using-css).

I first tried

```
<colgroup>
  ...
  <col style="visibility:hidden;">
  ...
</colgroup>
```

and also

```
<colgroup>
  ...
  <col style="display:none;">
  ...
</colgroup>
```

but neither has any effect. I noticed that other styling properties don't work either on <col>s either.
What can the <col> tag be used for, and what would be its typical use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<col class="slick"> does not apply class to the columns of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857437/col-class-slick-does-not-apply-class-to-the-columns-of-a-table)

Comment: `display:none` will not work, while `visibility:collapse` will. See https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

Answer (score 2):

that's because the col-element isn't "visible" in the first place, it's just an "alias" for the table columns. If you want to hide the second column for-example, apply it directly to the tds like:

```
tr td:nth-child(2)
{
 display: none;
 /* or */
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain why we would need the <col> tag in the first place.

Comment: You should not use (or, ahem, suggest) using the `display` and `visibility` properties interchangeably, they both exist for different purposes.

Comment: i thought I'd leave the decision to him, whatever his needs are... since he had both in his question...

Answer (score 2):

The `<col>` element only applies certain CSS properties to the cells within the targeted column. One of these properties is `visibility:collapse`, which will have the desired effect of hiding the entire column.

Therefore, to hide an entire column, the correct code would be

```
<col style="visibility: collapse;">
```

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

Answer (score 1):

## What is colgroup for?

The `colgroup` can be used the set the width, and only the width, of the columns of a given table.

## Solution for your use case

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857454/982075).

That means you need to apply the styles to each cell individually. You could try something like:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style type="text/css">
        table.myTable tr td:nth-child(4) {
            visibility:hidden;
        }
    </style>
    ...
```

where 4 is the index of the column.

[nth-child documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain why we would need the <col> tag in the first place.

Comment: @stevenvh It is handy to set the widths of the columns directly in html. I personally don't use it that often because I want to seperate markup from styling and thus use css instead. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: colgroup also allows background-color

Comment: you can also set background color and probably most css but not hide them. if you do you will hide only the col itself :(